# How to retrieve temporary credentials using REST API or by using AssumeRole in AWS SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've been trying to retrieve temporary credentials using role arn but getting an error of "EC2 Metadata not found" in AWS SDK.

Here is my approach:

```
AssumeRoleRequest request = new AssumeRoleRequest();
            request.RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::532634566192:role/ap-redshift";
            request.RoleSessionName = "newsessionanme";
            client = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient();
            AssumeRoleResponse resp = client.AssumeRole(request);
            Console.WriteLine(resp.Credentials);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

2nd approach

```
client = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient();
        var response = client.AssumeRole(new AssumeRoleRequest
        {
            RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::532634566192:role/ap-redshift",
            RoleSessionName = "newsessionanme"
        });
        AssumedRoleUser assumedRoleUser = response.AssumedRoleUser;
        Credentials credentials = response.Credentials;
```

This is the error I am getting:

> "Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.'"

This picture shows the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are fallbacks for fetching credentials when constructing AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient()

[FallbackCredentialsFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAinL.jpg)

This is an example for env vars I had to configure for getting temp creds from STS using AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityAsync:

```
 var oidcJwt = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(_awsWebIdentityTokenPath!); // from env var: AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE, note that this env var's value should contain a path to a file which contain JWT from OIDC...
 var stsClient =
        new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(); // On aws, stsClient will be constructed using the following env vars:
                                                // AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE, AWS_ROLE_ARN, AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME

    var assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityAsync(new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest
    {
        RoleArn = _awsRoleArn, // env var: AWS_ROLE_ARN
        WebIdentityToken = oidcJwt, // raw token, not path!
        RoleSessionName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()
    });
```

The following code was taken from the library (AWSSDK.SecurityToken)

```
  string environmentVariable1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE");
  string environmentVariable2 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ROLE_ARN");
  string environmentVariable3 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME");
```

Please follow the fallbacks and configure it for your needs.